# How do I cause my List to scroll to show the last line in the backing Array of String using SwiftUI under macOS

Tags: xcode, listview, swiftui, scroll, scrollviewreader

I've tried several solutions that I've found but none work for me, mostly lengthy with compile errors that I didn't understand how to fix.  I collaborated with an AI today and after the third iteration edited this compact solution that compiled - but the List still does not scroll automatically. I'm very, very new at Swift.

The backing Array of String is updated by a published and observableObject:

```
class Logger: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var messageArray = ["Start by selecting the project's data folder."]
    
    func addMessage(_ msg: String) {
        messageArray.append("\(timeNow()) *  \(msg)")
    }
```

I create an instance in my main (and only) ContentView

```
@ObservedObject var logger = Logger()
```

The code below is in a VStack and updates but does not scroll when the messageArray is changed by some other code.  It is for macOS not IOS

```
    List(logger.messageArray, id: \.self) {
        message in
        Text(message)
    }
    .padding()
    .background(ScrollViewReader { proxy in
        Color.clear.onAppear {
            proxy.scrollTo(logger.messageArray.last)
        }
        .onReceive(logger.$messageArray) { _ in
            withAnimation {
                proxy.scrollTo(logger.messageArray.last)
            }
        }
    })
```

I hope you can help me with this as I've spent way too much time on it.

Comment: You shouldn’t be using ObservedObject where the object is owned — use StateObject instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this approach, to scroll to the last line of the list.
It uses the important `id` and `.onChange()` and has the `ScrollViewReader` wrapping the `List`. Works for me.

```
class Logger: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var messageArray = ["message"]
    
    func addMessage(_ msg: String) {
        messageArray.append("\(UUID().uuidString.prefix(5)) *  \(msg)") // <-- for testing
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var logger = Logger() // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            List (logger.messageArray, id: \.self) { message in
                Text(message).id(message) // <-- here, need id
            }
            .onChange(of: logger.messageArray) { _ in    // <-- here
                withAnimation {
                    proxy.scrollTo(logger.messageArray.last)
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
        Button("Add message") {
            logger.addMessage("test message")  // <-- for testing
        }
    }
    
}
```